# lastmessageID always null except for me

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

## Presentation

**Goal**: Find when the last message of a designated was send

**How**: Use property of User, *lastmessageID*, fetch the message corresponding to this ID to find the property *createdTimestamp*

**Problem**: I'm the only one in the was doesn't have the property *lastmessageID* equal to null even if the user had send message a few minute ago

**Question**: Is it coming from my coding or from Discord.js ? Is there a way to bypass this problem ?

**NOTE**: I know it's cached:

- When someone send a message while the bot is alive give the same result.
- For the sake of the test, I summon a bot that so I give me  a"fresh" message when testing

## CODE SAMPLE

*every "**...**" is to protect personal data*

**SCRIPT**

```
  function findID() {
    var IDarray = userm.users.map((user) => user.lastMessageID)
    console.log("IDarray: ", IDarray)
    var ID = IDarray[0]
    console.log("ID: ", ID)
    msg(ID)
  }

  function msg(lastmsgID) {
    var lastmsg = message.channel.messages.fetch(lastmsgID).then(message => time(message)).catch(console.error);
  }

  function time(msg){
    ...
  }

  findID();
```

---

---

**RESULTS
WITH ME**

```
user:  [
  User {
    id: '...',
    bot: false,
    username: '...',
    discriminator: '....',
    avatar: '...',
    flags: UserFlags { bitfield: ... },
    lastMessageID: '...',
    lastMessageChannelID: '...'
  }
]
IDarray:  [ '...' ]
ID:  ...
<Wed Oct 07 2020 00:30:52 GMT+0200 (GMT+02:00)> : Recieved Message to ..., content /test <@!...>
Date as YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss ==> 2020-10-07 00:30:54
```

**RESULTS
WITH ANYONE**

```
user:  [
  User {
    id: '...',
    bot: false,
    username: '...',
    discriminator: '...',
    avatar: '...',
    lastMessageID: null,
    lastMessageChannelID: null,
    flags: UserFlags { bitfield: ... }
  }
]
IDarray:  [ null ]
ID:  null
<Wed Oct 07 2020 00:26:44 GMT+0200 (GMT+02:00)> : Recieved Message to ..., content /test <@...>
Date as YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss ==> NaN-aN-aN aN:aN:aN
```

*If you think I can improve this question by anyway, don't hesitate to tell me !
Thanks for reading !*

Comment: You said that messages were sent just a few minutes ago, but have you reset your bot since then?

Comment: I know it's cached and even when someone send a message while the bot is alive give the same result. For the sake of the test, I summon bots (!help for example), so I always have a "fresh" message when testing

Answer (score 0):

Try `client.users.fetch('uid');` to fetch the user then pull the info you need. This pulls updates the user from Discord not from the cache.

Comment: It's still null

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem with the cache. The bot will only give lastMessage if the message was sent after the bot is started. You would need to fetch all the messages from all the channels for it to work, or just wait for the users to post a message after to bot is started.